# how to do Enum.sort_by & search with created_at date Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have this data,

```
[       
  %{
    company_id: "ocsc.ie",
    created_at: "Wednesday, 08 Mar 2017  6:14 AM",
    name: "O&#39;Connor Sutton Cronin",
    session_count: 2,
    user_count: 8
  },
  %{
    company_id: "virtuspm.ie",
    created_at: "Tuesday, 10 Jul 2018  8:48 AM",
    name: "VIRTUS",
    session_count: 1,
    user_count: 7
  },
  %{
    company_id: "garlandconsultancy.com",
    created_at: "Wednesday, 20 Jun 2018  3:32 PM",
    name: "Garland",
    session_count: 1,
    user_count: 3
  },
  %{
    company_id: "protectorsecurity.co.uk",
    created_at: "Friday, 31 Aug 2018 11:03 AM",
    name: "Protector Security Group",
    session_count: 4,
    user_count: 9
  },
  %{
    company_id: "tcd.ie",
    created_at: "Wednesday, 01 Mar 2017  7:39 AM",
    name: "TCD",
    session_count: 4,
    user_count: 18
  }
]
```

I am trying to sort this according to different values.

```
 Enum.sort_by(data, &(&1.user_count), &Kernel.>=/2)
```

Integer and string both, the above expression is working.

I have tried for integer values, my concern is how we can sort by date?
Also, can we search through values? with `like` expression? just for `name` and `company_id`, where you pass the search query as `gar`.

```
  [%{
    company_id: "garlandconsultancy.com",
    created_at: "Wednesday, 20 Jun 2018  3:32 PM",
    name: "Garland",
    session_count: 1,
    user_count: 3
  }]
```

.
So all those maps which are similar to search query filtered.

I have tried this

```
Enum.filter(data, fn(x) -> String.match?(String.downcase(x.name), ~r/String.downcase("VIR")/) end)
```

It's not working either.Any help would be so thankful.

Comment: Use https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#compare/2 for datetime sorting, but convert your strings to datetimes first. Try Timex library for datetime parsing (https://github.com/bitwalker/timex).

Comment: and for searching?

Comment: And for searching wait for another answer. You've posted two questions here.

Comment: If you happen to like an answer below, please mark it as the solution :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest route you can take it to first parse all your datetime strings using a library like Timex.

You can parse a date using directives to fit your specific format.

```
def parse_timestamp(ts) do 
  Timex.parse!(ts, "{WDfull}, {0D} {Mshort} {YYYY}  {h12}:{m} {AM}")
end
```

For example:

```
iex(1)> parse_timestamp("Tuesday, 10 Jul 2018  8:48 AM")
~N[2018-07-10 08:48:00]
```

You can then use these values to sort your data by calling:

```
data 
|> Enum.sort_by(fn d -> d.created_at |> parse_timestamp() end, &Timex.before?/2)
```

Comment: My timestamp is parsed and I am using the code

```Enum.sort_by(data, &(&1["created_at"]), &DateTime.compare(&1, &2))```

but this raises an error
    **(CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: :gt**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, I got it.
For anyone else facing the same issue I am posting the final solution as another answer

Answer (score 3):

Although the [Enum documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sort/2) states what has already been written in the answer by Christophe but that doesn't work as it will throw an error **(CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: :gt **

If you are facing the same issue you will need to explicitly call true and false for the :gt/:lt value something like this

```
data
|> Enum.sort(fn map1, map2 -> 
  case DateTime.compare(map1[date_key], map2[date_key]) do
    :lt -> true
    _ -> false
  end
end)
```

This sorts the data in increasing order of date_key. Also, I have not included the steps of parsing the date for which you can refer the above written answer.

Comment: Actually you can pass the `DateTime` module name instead of a `fn` and elixir will automatically use its `compare` function. So you do not have to cast to boolean yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, you have to interpolate `String.downcase("VIR")`

```
Enum.filter(data, fn x ->
      to_find = String.downcase("VIR")
      String.match?(String.downcase(x.name), ~r/#{to_find}/)
    end)
```

In this case you can use [`String.contains?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#contains?/2) instead of `String.match?/2`

For time comparison, use [Timex](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/getting-started.html) library (as denis.peplin said in the comments)